# How to go from specs/requirements to design, architecture, code, tests, documentation for embedded systems?

Tags: microcontroller, c, design, firmware

How do professional embedded systems engineers design, architect, code, test, document systems?

Any good examples, libraries, resources that showcase the process of going from specs/requirements to system design, diagrams, architecture, coding, testing, documentation?

For RTOS versus no operating system code? So we can see the difference and thought process?

Ideally it would showcase things like: a hardware abstraction layer, modularity, classes, different types of tests - from mock tests, whitebox, blackbox, integration tests, security tests and so on?

And perhaps can be compiled, tested on a computer before porting over to the end platform (ESP32 or STM or Arduino .etc.)

Any examples for safety critical systems, medical devices? Versus less critical systems so we can see the difference in rigour or tests?

I'm trying to improve and got sick of hacking things together and not understanding how to properly engineer reliable embedded systems...

Thanks for helping a junior embedded systems engineer!

Comment: You're basically asking us how to run a successful embedded development company :) I bet a lot of us would love to know how you can do that!

Comment: True! I'm hoping that NASA or a company has an open source example of a project from start to finish (or a paid course?) for uni students and new engineers to look at. I can understand if it's proprietary and they'd be out of business if everyone knew how to do this..  But if we're to elevate the quality of graduates, new engineers and the code in this industry then resources like this are needed? And we need to share what experts/veterans know? 

The software industry seems a lot more open.

Comment: @TharunSonti Anyone who has such a complete design won't release it because it was done for money. You say software industry is more open but are there actually free designs available as complete as you just requested with documentation, design specs, and testing? I don't believe it. Software development consists of less parts. Embedded development consists of both hardware and software so is inherently more complex which mean less people, which means less availability in general. Even if everything was on par with software development which it's not.

Comment: @TharunSonti honestly, I doubt anyone would go out of business if more people knew how to build good embedded hardware. There would just be more good embedded hardware and less terribly misdesigned stock router devices being mis-customized to do terrible things they were never designed for...

Comment: @TharunSonti it's just that you can literally study *product design* for years, even as a university program. You can also study hardware design for manufacturing. Hardware / Software-Codesign. System testing. Requirements engineering. Technical Writing. What you describe is the full education of 4 to 8 engineers, plus  very likely someone who knows how to negotiate prices vs features and deadlines with customers.

Comment: Professional embedded systems engineers don't use ESP32 or Arduino.

Comment: Anyway, the things you mention are all briefly touched by a decent engineering university degree. Which is why such degrees are good: you get to scratch the surface of a lot of different topics, getting a rough idea of the big picture. And then in your profession, you will not work with all of these. You'll probably focus on a few areas, maybe specialize deeper in some.

Comment: There is no recipe for doing that. And there can't be such a recipe. It's like asking, how one should select furniture for a home. It's a matter of taste and millions of different paths lead to acceptable goals.

Answer (score 2):

**The biggest weakness I usually see is documentation**

The first thing is decide how you're going to document your projects.  I've had very good results from "basic" software such as Mediawiki.

Then decide on your process.  Typically it's Spec, Design, Prototype, Test, Design-for-production, Implement.  All with various kinds of interlock, iteration, and back annotation.  It's worth reading some companies' ISO 9001 quality handbooks, not necessarily in engineering, for a sense of what some companies formalise.  (Very many are published, easy to find.)

Number everything!  "I think we need to change the spec in spec para 1.2.3.4 because the parts available in design-for-production para 2.3.4.5 have a different noise immunity."   Keeping the paragraph numbering static can be a challenge.  Numbering everything means you can cross refer to everything, including in phone calls.  Make sure circuit diagrams etc have good document numbering and grids, so you can refer to areas easily.

Insist on discipline and reasoning in version control commit messages.  Usually the best place for this is in the branch merge (using git terminology), rather than the line-by-line edits.

Keep hardware, firmware and software version control locked in sync.

Budget good time for documentation.  It's not window-dressing.

Comment: The most common shortcut taken is probably skipping various documentation. Particularly things like internal engineering documentation of why a PCB or piece of code was designed the way it was and how it works. The kind of things that are pure gold for the person picking up the project after you. This is the stuff we really should be doing, yet ends up lowest priority time and again...

Answer (score 1):

That you are sick of hacking pieces together is a good sign.

One key to success is an awareness of the vast # of ways a design/solution can fail.

Gossip over a beer is one way, so you can learn from other's errors and oversights and responses to schedule pressure.

I primarily develop high dynamic range analog systems, that must perform well when subjected to ugly interference. One advantage of such tasks is the continuous change of values, unlike the behavior of state machines.

I suggest that you focus on how to put boxes around the numerous state machines in your solutions so that the dependencies are very, very clear. Even a 1-MCU solution may have numerous intertwined state machines.

There was a language 30 years ago called Modula, which had very strong typing and very strong declarations of data-flow (by proclaiming PORTS and directions).

A big part of my circuit/system designs involve methods needed to better approach a perfect abstracted behavior of circuits, even if the raw VDD is trash-laden.

Apply that same mindset to embedded systems: how to avoid flaws.

===============================

I'm assisting a project having embedded microcontrollers and impact sensors. Over the last year, the noise floor has been reduced from 90,000 uV peak to 500 uV peak-to-peak, thus nearly 40dB noise/trash/glitch reduction.

The principal engineer has also recoded the entire software suite, at least 2 times.

He's achieved far more observability of waveforms, moved from NO concurrency to 5+ concurrent math modules, inserted "big-data neural-net" signal recognition for a 2_D impact (X and Y) point prediction, and restructured the system timing for better anti-aliasing performance once the "informative frequencies" are understood.

Notice the massive "go at it, once again". Iterate. And have that built into the schedule milestones.

Comment: +1 for suggesting getting state machines very clear. Can't remember where, but I have seen a tool that will generate the state machine from a friendly representation, which I think is a good idea. If you automate massaging it, and keep it separate, then you don't have to touch it, and can regenerate at will if the metadata changes. Then what you've done becomes reusable for other state machines. Regen every automated build to prevent indiscriminate manual mods. And appointing a Szar over that "framework" might help. (Check-in notifications, modification approvals required, + inspections).